# Cloudflare - PHP and Javascript Includes not Working

Tags: javascript, php, cloudflare

Since implementing Cloudflare some of my includes aren't working.

One specific example: Inside the includes folder, I have a sub folder "texter". Here I have a php page that references a Javascript library in the same folder. The page receives a GET request with variables, then parses on the parameters to an external 3rd party API.

When Cloudflare is disabled/paused the mini app works.

I'm using Page Rules to disable Cloudflare activity for my includes folder but it's still not working.

e.g. Pattern: `*mysite.com/includes/*`  - With all rules and chache set to disabled.

How can I get my web app running while Cloudflare is also running? Am I on the right track? Thanks in advance.

Edit: I'm using htaccess to limit direct access to these directories... could this cause an issue?

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm...this goes away with us paused? Do you have something like Rocket Loader turned on in your performance settings (can potentially impact jQuery or JavaScript).

Do any error messages appear at all?

Comment: Hi thanks for responding. No errors, and not using Rocket Loader. I'd love to use that, but when I turn that on a couple of my other plugins break. To stay on topic though. Yes, the includes app works when Cloudflare is paused.

Comment: Any ideas? I can't really use Cloudflare if it breaks my site.

Comment: Really needs to be looked at in a support ticket so we know the domain. We don't impact PHP at all by default & we really need to see what's going on.

Comment: OK that would be great I'll head over there.

Comment: FYI I logged a ticket weeks ago and no one has gotten back to me.